# What's the need to call DataBindingUtil.setContentView() when using Data Binding Library?

Tags: android, performance, android-databinding

I am learning to use Data Binding Library. I came to know that it removes the need to call findViewById() manually and makes the code more robust and readable.

To understand the use, I did the following:

1. made a temp_layout.xml which contains 2 text views with ids 'tv1' and 'tv2'
2. added the `<layout>` tag as root
3. clicked on 'build project'

Now I found that a new 'TempLayoutBinding' class was available which contained the variables 'tv1' and 'tv2'.

**My question is that**, even when I already specified the `<layout>` tag in the temp_layout.xml, why do I still need to call `mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...)`?
What specifically does it do?

Comment: and why do you call `Activity#setContentView` ? then this is the same reason why you call `DataBindingUtil#setContentView`

Comment: @pskink I think that in case of activity, we need to specify which layout file to inflate. But in the data binding case, I have already defined the `<layout>` tag. (It even got the variables by going through the view ids) So shouldn't the binding class generated already know which layout I am talking about? Am I right?

Comment: see [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/data-binding/extensions/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java#260) and [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/data-binding/extensions/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java#274), note the line #276

Comment: So this means 'it is just the way it is coded'. In case of an activity, `Activity#setContentView` helps render the view. With data binding, `DataBindingUtil#setContentView` should not have a role in rendering the UI as the activity is already calling that method inside itself. Therefore I don't think that the reason is "exactly same" in this case too.

Comment: Okay maybe it is true. But then what does the `<layout>` tag does?

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: if you dont want to use `DataBindingUtil#setContentView` you can still use `Activity#setContentView` but you would need to call `DataBindingUtil#bind` method also

Comment: if you use kotlin-extension it also removes `findViewById()`. And you can directly access the id in the layout.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What the regular `setContentView(layoutRes)` does is display your UI in the current activity and inflates it into a view that's added to the Activity Context, so you can call findViewById and other methods over the inflated layout.

In data binding, the regular `setContentView(layoutRes)` is replaced with `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(context, layoutRes)`, it does all the above plus creating the binding object, it does findViewById and all other data binding related tasks under the hood and gives you the binding object that's ready for use.

Comment: If `DataBindingUtil#setContentView` does all the job needed, the only question left is: what's the role of `<layout>` tag? What exactly does it do?

Comment: @vaibhavS I believe that it points the Data Binding library to the layout so it creates the `TempLayoutBinding` class so you can use it in the java code.

Answer (score 3):

`DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` set the Activity's content view to the given layout and return the associated binding. It is same as Activity's `setContentView()`.

If you not call `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` or `setContentView()`, you will only get a blank screen.

Comment: The activity to which the layout belongs will already be calling `Activity#setContentView`. So there shouldn't be a blank screen. The views may not be set but they should at least exist (and would probably be showing their default value). Don't you think?

Comment: You don't need to call Activity#setContentView ,if you are using DataBinding.  The only thing you need to call is  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(). This set's your activity's view and also bind your view.